# How to know which constraint in CP-SAT did not meet the feasibility gap

Tags: constraint-programming, or-tools, cp-sat, irreducible-infeasible-subset

Is there any systematic way to retrieve some information on the constraint that caused infeasibility in Or.Tools CP-SAT?

```
using System;
using Google.OrTools.Sat;

public class InfeasibleCpModel
{
  static void Main()
  {
    CpModel _cpModel = new CpModel();

    IntVar x = _cpModel.NewIntVar(0, 10, "x");
    IntVar y = _cpModel.NewIntVar(0, 10, "y");
    
    _cpModel.AddAllDifferent(new IntVar[]{x, y})
    _cpModel.Add(x == y);
    
    CpSolver solver = new CpSolver();
    CpSolverStatus status = solver.Solve(_cpModel);
    
    if (status == CpSolverStatus.Infeasible)
    {
        // Catch the constraint that did not meet the feasibility gap
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that, in general, one cannot identify a single constraint that causes infeasibility. What you can try to do is find an "irreducible infeasible subset" of constraints -- a set of constraints that cannot be simultaneously satisfied, such that omitting any one of them lets the solver satisfy the rest.

Comment: That is correct. This question is more about how a particular solver reports on those constraints that could not meet the feasibility gap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet, see https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/973

For debugging I would recommend you to divide your constraints into groups so you can activate/deactivate some of them to pin down the infeasibility